# function to calculate the values of an insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table to which I insert 10000 records:

```
[inUcastPktsAll] INT,
[inMcastPktsAll] INT,
[inBcastPktsAll] INT,
[outUcastPktsAll] INT,
[outMcastPktsAll] INT,
[outBcastPktsAll] INT
```

```
| inUcastPktsAll| inMcastPktsAll| inBcastPktsAll| outUcastPktsAll| outMcastPktsAll| outBcastPktsAll|
| --------------| ------------- | ------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 58745586      | 8759574       | 45878         | 78547852       | 9663655        | 2358545        |
...
```

Is there any way to convert/change the value of the data as it is being inserted into the table. Using the following formula: (Total IP Packets x 10) / 1024.

```
| inUcastPktsAll| inMcastPktsAll| inBcastPktsAll| outUcastPktsAll| outMcastPktsAll| outBcastPktsAll|
| --------------| ------------- | ------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 573687        | 85542         | 458           | 767068         | 94371          | 23032          |
...
```

A function or procedure that converts values without relying on the insertion instruction.
I'd appreciate an idea.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using generated columns:

```
alter table t add inUcastPktsAll_100 as (inUcastPktsAll * 10 / 1024);
```

Then you can just see the modified results by referring to the new columns.